# Override setter in @ConfigurationProperties with list type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I am using **Spring Boot 1.5.15** and I am having some trouble during the reading of a bean annotated with the annotation `@ConfigurationProperties`.

In details, I am trying to use the following bean.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "permissions")
public class Permissions {
    private List<String> permissions;
    private Set<String> permissionsSet;

    public List<String> getPermissions() {
        return this.permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<String> permissions) {
        this.permissionsSet = new HashSet<>(permissions)
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    // Other code
}
```

The corresponding `application.yml` is the following.

```
permissions:
  permissions:
    - ROLE_1
    - ROLE_2
```

The problem I am facing is that the member `permissionsSet` is always empty. I debugged the application, and I found that Spring uses the following workflow to create the bean.

1. Default constructor calling
2. Setter calling with an empty list
3. Injection of the correct value for the list after the setter calls.

Is this the right behaviour? I am trying to find any reference in the documentation, but I cannot find anything.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why not directly go with a set for 'permissions'?

Comment: Because Spring does not allow to inject values directly into a `Set` :(

Comment: interesting, that feature seems to have been added in a later version then, cause I've seen code that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's right is debatable, as you noticed, it's what happens.

If you only have a small set of permissions (like a handful), the easiest solution would be to just have the getter return

```
return Sets.newHashset(permissions)
```

or the like. In most cases, the performance drawback won't matter.

If you fear performance issues you can initialize `permissionsSet` as `null` and properly initialize it the first time the getter is used (i.e. initialize it from `permissions` if it is null).

Alternatively, you can try `@PostConstruct` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) for official documentation) or other options to initialize the bean after construction with custom code to initialize `permissionSet`, but I'd consider this overkill for this example.

Comment: It was a toy example, not the real code I am using. Thanks for the `@PostConstruct` hint, but I also asked for some documentation. Have you any?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin sorry, I have no documentation for the implementation of the ConfigurationProperties injection. Added a link to the official documentation for PostConstruct.